# Cross compilation: can't resolve symbol 'register_printf_function'

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I have cross-compiled strongswan-5.2.2, a open source project implementing VPN server&client, for embedded-linux running on mipsel (target) on Ubuntu12.04 running on Intel x86 machine.

But executing the cross-compiled strongswan on mipsel machine fails as follows:

```
$ ./charon
./charon: can't resolve symbol 'register_printf_function'
```

It seems like that `libc.so` is not refereed by the executable. The reason why I think like that is `register_print_function` is implemented in `libc.so` (AFAIK). However, `libc.so` already exists on `/lib` of target mipsel machine.

Inspecting all of shared libraries referred by the executable shows:

```
$ readelf -d ./charon | grep NEEDED
 0x000001 (NEEDED)  Shared Library: [libm.so.0]
 0x000001 (NEEDED)  Shared Library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x000001 (NEEDED)  Shared Library: [libdl.so.0]
 0x000001 (NEEDED)  Shared Library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x000001 (NEEDED)  Shared Library: [libc.so.0]
```

All of the above libraries exist on `/lib` of target machine..

Why is that error message coming up, yet I have all of the shared libraries required by the executable on target machine? And... how can I solve the problem?

**Update:**

```
$ nm -D libc.so.0 
...
0002fb70 T register_printf_fuction
...
```

That function is already implemented in the shared library, isn't it...?

Comment: Curious if you ever found a solution to your problem. I have the same problem, but can't find suggestions other than to compile glibc, which is not an option for my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`register_printf_function` is specific to GNU [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). If your target machine has some other [libc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (e.g. dietlibc or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)) it is not available.

you may compile `glibc` for your target machine (probably difficult) or find a strongswan specific workaround

Check with `nm -D /lib/libc.so` that the target libc has a `register_printf_function`

Comment: `uclibc` is installed on target mips machine. `$ strings libc.so.0` shows a string `register_printf_function`. Thus I believe that function is already implemented in the target machine's shared library.